# getting the id of an inner item in a table due to a right click

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the id of a `span` inside of a `tr` when I right click on it. I saw several posts that suggest `$(this).attr('id')` or `this.id`, but all of these only return the id of the entire table.

My html code:

```
<table id="table_id">
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b>title</b></td>
        </tr>               
        <tr>
            <td class="table_row_message" colspan="2">
                <span onclick="toggleItem('trigger',1);" id="span_id_trigger1"> 
                                <span id="item1" class="toggle">text</span>
                                &nbsp;
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I am trying to get the 'id="span_id_trigger1"'

my JQuery code

```
function testMenu(){
    $("#table_id").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    // Avoid the real one
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(stuff I tried to print the id);
    $(".custom-menu").toggle(100).
    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
    return false;
});
```

I also have window.onload = testMenu, to make sure it is loading properly. As I said I keep getting the table_id no matter where i right click in the table

Comment: have you tried `$(".table_row_message span').attr('id')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to travel the DOM. Since you have 2 spans, you'll need to use `:not()`<sup>1</sup>:

```
console.log($(event.target).closest('tr').find('span:not(.toggle)').prop('id'));
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>You could omit that part since `prop` return the id of the first element, which is what you are trying to target.</sub>

Comment: The problem with the above code is that if I have another row with spans it will only return the first id every time

Comment: @Quantico Updated my answer, it should work for multiple `tr`.

Comment: This is great. One final question, in case I would like to also get the table id, would I have to do an if/else statement?

Comment: @Quantico What do you mean? You can simply use 2 variables : `var id1 = this.id; ver id2 = code above`.

Comment: I guess I can and just do if id2 is undefined use id1

Comment: You can do `var id = $(event.target).closest('tr').find('span:not(.toggle)').prop('id') || this.id`.